# SSRS query for only data from current quarter?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying to create an T-SQL query t that only shows data from the current quarter.

My data table looks as follows.

NAME ,  DATE

Alice     ,  1-1-2013

Bob       ,  12-1-2013

Charles   ,  12-15-2013

At any given time when I run the report I'd like to be able to see only data from the current quarter I'm in.  So if Today is 12-18-14 then when I run the report, I'd like to only see entries with dates from 10-1-14 through 12-31-14 so

Bob, 12-1-2013

Charles, 12-15-2013

I welcome any hints. I have searched thoroughly but am just not experienced enough to piece together the partial answers using CASE statements.

Thanks. 
MC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I don't think you need a CASE statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,GETDATE()),0)
    AND Date < DATEADD(dd,1,DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,-1,GETDATE()),-1))
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1884f/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Year(Date) = Year(GETDATE())
  AND DATENAME(qq,Date) = DATENAME(qq,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to get the desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE DATEPART(QUARTER,DateColumnName) = DATEPART(QUARTER,GETDATE())
AND YEAR(DateColumnName) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```